# how do i implement a python unit-test for a method which accepts filepath as argument?

Tags: python, python-unittest

```
class A:
    def read_json(self,file_json_path):
        try:
            with open(file_json_path) as fd:
                content = json.dumps(fd)
         except IOError:
            print 'exception while opening a file %s\n'%(file_json_path)
```

I am new to python can anyone guide me, how to mock an opening a file and read json data.

Comment: I would use a small known json file, and you'd know the relative path as the testdata folder would probably be a subfolder of where the test is.

Comment: You should use tempfile. It deletes it straight after you close it.

Answer (score -1):

You'll want to look into [mock_open](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#mock-open) from the mock module.  It lets you patch the built in open method to fake reading/writing.

If have this function (note I changed your function a bit):

```py
def read_json(file_json_path):
    try:
        with open(file_json_path) as fd:
            content = json.load(fd)
            return content
    except IOError:
        print('exception while opening a file %s\n' % (file_json_path))
```

You can easily test the function with something like this:

```py
def test_read_json():
    from unittest.mock import mock_open, patch

    m = mock_open(read_data = '{"key": "value"}')
    with patch('__main__.open', m):
        result = read_json('fake_file')
        assert result == {'key': 'value'}
    m.assert_called_once_with('fake_file')
```

Comment: Please a little more context to you answer. Explain why it is a good idea to use mock_open and it would be very helpful if you could provide some code snippets for the same